# SSD encryption and backups

Tags: backup, ssd, encryption

I'm looking to increase security by getting a popular 256 GB SSD that comes with 3D MLC and 256 bit AES encryption.   That looks to be the ticket.  But. . . I have a very sophisticated back-up system where once a month or so, I drag "My Documents" into a folder named after the date of said dragging onto a USB flash drive.  Will the dragged data be encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Full Disk Encryption is transparent for operating system. OS has access only to unencrypted data and copies files as streams of unencrypted bytes. Files are encrypted when they are being written to SSD and immediately decrypted when they are being read.

Comment: I was afraid of that. . .  Is there a way to encrypt my "sophisticated" back-up USB flash drive protocol?  I've moved from mostly clueless to completely clueless in one instant.

Comment: I'm not sure if using Full Disk Encryption solutions on flash drives is secure. If it's just a read-only backup, then you could `tar` and encrypt your files before copying, but they won't be accessible transparently - you'll have to decrypt and un-`tar` them first.